# SQL How to include result not found in other table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

Table1 'Profile'

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | John |
| 02 | Wayne |
| 03 | Eve |

Table2 'Check_In'

| PID | CDate |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-06-25 |
| 02 | 2021-06-25 |

If I use this query:

```
SELECT Profile.Name, Check_In.CDate 
FROM Profile
LEFT JOIN Check_In ON Check_In.PID = Profile.ID
```

I will get this result

| Name | CDate |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-06-25 |
| Wayne | 2021-06-25 |
| Eve | null |

This is the intended result, but because it will have check the whole `Check_In` table for each `Profile` record, the time used to generate the result is not favorable.

So I was looking into this query:

```
SELECT Profile.Name, Check_In.CDate 
FROM Check_In
LEFT JOIN Profile ON Check_In.PID = Profile.ID
```

But the result is

| Name | CDate |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-06-25 |
| Wayne | 2021-06-25 |

Where Eve is missing (because Eve is a new personnel and her record has never existed in `Check_In` table), any method for me to include Eve in the result with null value for `CDate` as in the first scenario?

Comment: Why is `Check_In` used in both the `FROM` and the `LEFT JOIN` clause in your second query??

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a mistake, updated post with correct join table

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In case of left join it will take all the rows of the table that is on left side, so in the second query the left table is Check_In and it doesn't have Eve in it.

you can use the full outer join to get the Eve data in the result.

Use this query

SELECT Profile.Name, Check_In.CDate
FROM Check_In
FULL OUTER JOIN Profile ON Check_In.PID = Profile.ID

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason - if you want to have **all** rows from `Profile`, then you need to use `Profile` In the `FROM` clause - and do a `LEFT JOIN` on `Check_In` - try this:

```
SELECT Profile.Name, Check_In.CDate 
FROM Profile
LEFT JOIN Check_In ON Check_In.PID = Profile.ID
```

The `LEFT JOIN` by definition returns **all rows** from the table to the left of the `JOIN` operator - and joins those rows from the right-hand table that exist (and returns NULL for those rows where the JOIN condition doesn't match the right-hand table).